# Spark: Combine columns in dataframe with a character between them

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a number of columns in a spark dataframe that I want to combine into one column and add a separating character between each column. I don't want to combine all the columns together with the character separating them, just some of them. In this example, I would like to add a pipe between the values of everything besides the first two columns.

Here is an example input:

```
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+
|id | detail | context  |     col3 |     col4|
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| 1 | {blah} | service  | null     | null    |
| 2 | { blah | """ blah | """blah} | service |
| 3 | { blah | """blah} | service  | null    |
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+
```

The expected output would be something like this:

```
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+--------------------------------+
|id | detail | context  |     col3 |     col4| data 
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+--------------------------------+
| 1 | {blah} | service  | null     | null    | service||
| 2 | { blah | """ blah | """blah} | service | """blah|"""blah}|service
| 3 | { blah | """blah} | service  | null    | """blah}|service|
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+--------------------------------+
```

Currently, I have something like the following:

```
val columns = df.columns.filterNot(_ == "id").filterNot(_ =="detail")
val nonulls = df.na.fill("")
val combined = nonulls.select($"id", concat(columns.map(col):_*) as "data")
```

The above combines the columns together, but doesn't add in the additional character. If I tried these possibilities, but I'm obviously not doing it right:

```
scala> val combined = nonulls.select($"id", concat(columns.map(col):_|*) as "data")

scala> val combined = nonulls.select($"id", concat(columns.map(col):_*, lit('|')) as "data")

scala> val combined = nonulls.select($"id", concat(columns.map(col):_*|) as "data")
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! :) Thanks!

Comment: `""" blah` is this supposed to be one string?

Comment: @mtoto yes it's one string. just showing that some of the column values could have spaces as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
val columns = df.columns.filterNot(_ == "id").filterNot(_ =="detail") 
val columnsWithPipe = columns.flatMap(colname => Seq(col(colname),lit("|"))).dropRight(1)
val combined = nonulls.select($"id",concat(columnsWithPipe:_*) as "data")
```

Comment: This works! Why do you turn it into a flatMap and use the `dropRight`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the concat_ws function ... it concatenates columns with a separator of your choice.

It's imported as
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws